# mod_redirect: non www to www.domain.name & www. domain name to (no hardcoding)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking forward to do the following redirects:

1. non www domains to www.domain.com ex:

   - cnn.com to www.cnn.com
2. www subdomains to non www subdomains ex:

   - www.test.cnn.com to test.cnn.com
   - www.test.cool.cnn.com to test.cool.cnn.com

i want both to be on the same htaccess file without hardcoding the domain name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a www to any host:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.%2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

To remove www from subdomains:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)\.([^.]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.%2.%3/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ [NC]`, since the trailing part is not in any way special. In fact, `.local` as a suffix was, and probably still is in some places, in use, and would not match {2,4}.